# How to stop a form zooming out of a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, materialize

I have a div here with a form in it and despite setting the div to fixed, the form inside it will not fix at all and zooms out of the bottom of it when the page is zoomed in and out (browser). I have tried all sorts, such as setting `style="position:fixed;"` in the form's inline css and copying the style of the parent div and putting it in the form's inline css but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

```html
<main role="main" class="mx-auto">
   {% load staticfiles %}

   <div style="position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%">
      <img src="{% static "img/shard.jpg" %}" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 100% 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></img>
      <div style="background-color: white; padding: 0% 3% {% if messages %}1%{% else %}1.5%{% endif %}3%; width: 58%; position: fixed; right: 10%; top:30%; bottom:20%; box-shadow: 0 4px 16px -7px gray;">
         <form method="POST" class="" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center" style="padding-top:3%">Login</h1>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder=Username>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required placeholder=Password>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block center-align" type="submit">Login</button>
         </form>
         <div class="center-align" style="padding-top:5px">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #151515;">Register</button>
         </div>

         <div style="padding-top:10px">
            {% if messages %}
               {% for message in messages %}
               <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {{ message }}
               </div>
               {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</main>
```

I just want it to stay fixed with the div! (which does not resize when zooming).

Comment: you do not provide a lot of info so this is a bit of a guess but try setting min-height on this div: <div style="position: fixed; width: 50%; height: 100%">

Comment: @StevenKuipers doesn't work -- that div is for the image btw, which takes up the right half of the screen and does not distort when zooming

Comment: I've had this issue a few times when doing frontend and it always pisses me off. For now, I made the inner div relative which causes the form to stick to the div so the div background expands with the form when zooming. I then made outermost div absolute so that the page can be scrolled down at least